# New Install of MinGW Issue with Compilation and Executable

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, compiler-construction, mingw

I used to have an older version of MinGW installed on my windows machine.

When I compiled my program under "Release" mode using the MinGW tool collection for build in NetBeans IDE, my executable was roughly 700KB.

Then, I recently installed the latest MinGW (mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe).

After the installation, I re-built my program and the executable is now 275KB and it doesn't seem to be reading the passed-in arguments correctly. The build is "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". It does have warnings for deprecation-related issues, but this existed before the new install.

I am really confused. Do you know what the problem is?

Thank you
Neo

Comment: This question lacks information, is your program doing something non-standard?  The argument parsing code would be useful to see anyhow.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what really happens?

Comment: @dmp - Yes, the program used to be fully functional before the new install of MinGW. It would print messages out to the command line when executed. The source code is identical since the new install of MinGW. I am using "MinGW" as the tool collection in the NetBeans build properties under "Relase". I'll try compiling using cygwin right now.

Comment: @ Joachim - I expect to see print messages in the console. I also expected the executable to be somewhat the same size, but it is now 275KB instead of 700KB. Right now, when it is executed in console, it displays nothing. It's odd because I did a clean+build and it showed "Build Successful"

Comment: Can you compile a simple hello world program and have it running?  The information you provide is not enough to diagnose the root cause of this.

Comment: @dmp - Ahhh. I just created a new project and it seems to be having problem with a simple hello world program. Here it is: <code>#include <stdlib.h> #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main(int argc, char** argv) { cout << "hello world" << endl; return (EXIT_SUCCESS); }</code> I used "Release" and "MinGW" as the tool collection to build. I then ran the executable in a command line and it just doesn't print any message. It's so odd to me because the build log shows "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"

Comment: Can you make a debug build and step through with the debugger?

Comment: @dmp - ok so I ran the deubgger, but it didn't show any message after hitting "hello world". Here are my MinGW settings:

Base Directory: C:\MinGW\bin
C Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
C++ Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
Fortran Compiler:C:\MinGW\bin\g77.exe
Assembler:C:\MinGW\bin\as.exe
Make Command:C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe
Debugger Command:C:\cygwin\bin\gdb.exe

The debugger command seems to be using the one inside the cygwin folder. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Can you open a command line, add `C:\MinGW\bin` to the path, and compile your hello world program using `gcc -g -o hello.exe hello.c` and see if running `hello.exe` works?  That should at least tell us if the problem is in the MinGW installation or in the NetBeans configuration.

Comment: @Michael - Okay, I added "C:\MinGW\bin" to the PATH in the environment variables and I removed "C:\cygwin\bin" from the PATH just to make sure. Then, I ran "g++ -g -o hello.exe main.cpp". The hello.exe worked! Does this mean it is a NetBeans configuration issue? I'm not sure what could be wrong in the configuration though. It is using the MinGW toolset under the Release build properties.

Comment: WOW. It works now. I think removing C:\cygwin\bin from the PATH fixed the problem. Ahhh. Is that right? That's strange though because I specifically told NetBeans to use the MinGW toolset. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: be careful not to mix toolchaines next time dude :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOW. It works now. I think removing C:\cygwin\bin from the PATH fixed the problem. Ahhh. Is that right? That's strange though because I specifically told NetBeans to use the MinGW toolset. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Keep in mind that the MinGW executables often launch sub-processes, and those the executables are searched for in various ways which include looking in the path (though I don't know the details of the search algorithm off the top of my head). So if a cygwin version of some program was picked up instead of the version in the MinGW distro, then I could certainly see things getting messed up..

Answer (score 1):

in this case you did mix compilers. paths matter mate.